# Amazon EC2 Free Tier - how to check how many free resources I used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Amazon offers 750 hours of EC2 linux and windows instances per month in "free tier".
Is there any way to see my "free tier" summary?

For example: "you used 153 out of 750 hours" ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, login to the aws.amazon.com console.

In the top right click on your name -> Billing & Cost Management -> Bill Details and you should see a very detailed list of what you have used so far in the current month.

Comment: In this section I can only see `$0.00 per Linux t1.micro instance-hour (or partial hour) under monthly free tier -- 3 Hrs ` so I have to check in free tier details how many resources I can use. Is there any sub page that shows both limit and usage ?

Comment: Best answer for me. Bill details shows how many hours each ec2 instance was used for the month.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but you could create an alert when you exceed the free tier like I created an `alert when the total AWS charges exceeds the minimum amount say 0.01$`, that should be good.

Please follow the instruction on [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/create-billing-alarm.html) to create an alert.

Comment: I already created rule for `0.00$` but this is not what I'am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: No I was able to set `0` as minimum. I am now notified about any charges.

Answer (score 0):

Some work arounds.

Way #1

you need enable programmatic access to aws billing data and save the billing data to nominated S3 bucket. Billing file format is csv.  The document is here:

http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-programmatic-access-to-aws-billing-data/

then run s3 sdk or awscli command to download these billing csv file to your local disk. You can program another code to read these csv files to get the information and generate report for your own request.

Way #2

using gem [amazon-pricing](https://github.com/CloudHealth/amazon-pricing) to get the billing

Comment: Far too complicated procedure for my billings around '1$'. Thanks.